# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /users/edit/ User has no profile

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I ran into a situation where I had developed a method called edit and passed both the profile and user forms into it when I wanted to modify a profile.

```
@login_required
def edit(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
            user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user,data=request.POST)
            profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile,data=request.POST,files=request.FILES)
            if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                  user_form.save()
                  profile_form.save()
      else:
            user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
            profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)          
      return render(request,'users/edit.html',{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form})
```

this is my views.py where i have written the logic

and coming to urls.py

```
path('edit/',views.edit,name='edit'),
```

and the edit.html code follows like this

```
{% extends 'users/base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<h2>Edit profile form</h2>
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ user_form.as_p }} 
            {{ profile_form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True)
      
      def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
```

The main project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/',include('users.urls'))
] 
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

the output shows me like this

[image: The result output]

I am expecting a better solution to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is no Profile model instance for that user. You may want to use django postsave signals to create a Profile model instance for any user that has been created.

To test this, use the admin page to create a Profile model instance for that user and check if it still generates the error.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have the admin page profile model is working fine.

Comment: So, when a user is created, a profile model instance for that user is not created, so create one for each user using a postsave signal